# Why does my javascript stop working on every other refresh of page? Script caching?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, refresh

I have a HTML page with a lot of javascript (sorry to be vague but I dont think the code is relevant) Since recently changing my code to include some drop down boxes, the javascript is only working on every other page refresh. e.g. It works when I click on the page, but then if I refresh it it doesn't work, then I refresh it again and it works etc. After doing a bit of googling I don't believe that this is anything to do with what is in my script but more to do with my script being cached. I have tried adding these lines of code to my page ...

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

But I am still getting the problem on every other refresh. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Being vague is one thing, but you don't provide any information that could be used to solve this problem. Are there any thrown errors?

Comment: It errors when populating the drop down boxes and will not execute any of the javascript after there. I can'ts ee any of ther errors, I just know that it stops working at that point.